# Running CRON every 10 seconds

Tags: bash, cron, cron-task

I have to run certain CRON every 10 seconds. I have following two methods to achieve what I want.

**Method 1**

Running same cron multiple times each with `sleep 10` seconds.

```
* * * * * php /path/to/php/file/to/execute >> /path/to/logs/logfile.log
* * * * * sleep 10; php /path/to/php/file/to/execute >> /path/to/logs/logfile.log
* * * * * sleep 20; php /path/to/php/file/to/execute >> /path/to/logs/logfile.log
* * * * * sleep 30; php /path/to/php/file/to/execute >> /path/to/logs/logfile.log
* * * * * sleep 40; php /path/to/php/file/to/execute >> /path/to/logs/logfile.log
* * * * * sleep 50; php /path/to/php/file/to/execute >> /path/to/logs/logfile.log
```

**Method 2**

Using `sh`. File `Cron.sh` has following code

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  php /path/to/php/file/to/execute
  sleep 10
done
```

Make Cron.sh file executable `chmod +x Cron.sh`

Run script in background `./Cron.sh &`

**Question**

Which of these two methods is better in terms of performance and overall?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods are actually different.

- Method 1 one will start 5 jobs at approximately the same time, run the sleep command and execute the jobs at about the desired time-offset.
- Method 2 will trigger the `sleep 10` after a job finished. This implies that it will not run every 10 seconds, but every 10 seconds plus the run-time of the job.

Besides the timing:

- Method 1 will run all jobs, independ of any of the other jobs. So there is the certainty that all jobs will run.
- Method 2 might terminate all remaining jobs in certain circumstances.

Method 1 might have some issues with race-conditions to the log-file.

Comment: I am marking this answer as accepted answer.  I will go for Method 1 then. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I've used both methods. **Method 1** is easier to setup, you just have some extra cron entries like:

```
* * * * * ( sleep 30 ; /path/myjob > /path/myjob.log 2>&1 )
```

But the more jobs you schedule the messier it can become if your job runs too long and starts to overlap. Also I don't like to have too much of these multiple jobs in my crontab and in my `ps` list. It will make it trickier if things in your job go wrong and you have to *pull the brakes* so to speak (needing to kill multiple processes and disabling multiple cron entries etc.). It will also make things trickier to update your code, automated deploys, CI/CD, Ansible, etc.

In **method 2** you will have to throw the php execution in the background to be able to run every 10 secs:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  php /path/to/php/file/to/execute &
  sleep 10
done
```

With something like this your job is easier to manage, but you have some other problems you have to code around. Like auto-restarting when it gets killed, handling signals, clean ways to start/restart/stop, etc.

About your question about *performance*.. that won't change much between these two methods. But if you want to really improve performance and lighten the system load you should *daemonize* this php script and let it execute a function periodically instead. Especially if you want to execute your job much more often in a minute.